# Why does reverse() work if the value of useState is an object and not if it is an array?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to use react hooks in my project and I have a problem with useState when I use array as value.

```
const List = () => {
    const [list, setList] = useState({ name: ["Bob", "Alice", "Dora"] })
    const reverseList = () => {
        setList({ name: list.name.reverse() })
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={reverseList}>Reverse</button>
            {list.name.map(name => name)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

above code works fine. but...

```
const List = () => {
    const [list, setList] = useState(["Bob", "Alice", "Dora"])
    const reverseList = () => {
        setList(list.name.reverse())
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={reverseList}>Reverse</button>
            {list.map(name => name)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

It doesn't work!! Can you please tell me why React works like this and what's the difference between the above codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first instance, you are setting state to a new object reference. In the second case, you are *not* setting a new object reference, you're calling `reverse` on the array, which *mutates it*.

In both cases, I would recommend making a shallow copy of the array and calling `reverse` so React knows that it's dealing with new state and therefore knows to re-render.

```js
const List = () => {
    const [list, setList] = useState({ name: ["Bob", "Alice", "Dora"] })
    const reverseList = () => {
        // Shallow copy
        setList({ name: [...list.name].reverse() })
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={reverseList}>Reverse</button>
            {list.name.map(name => name)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

```js
const List = () => {
    const [list, setList] = useState(["Bob", "Alice", "Dora"])
    const reverseList = () => {
        // Shallow copy
        setList([...list.name].reverse())
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={reverseList}>Reverse</button>
            {list.map(name => name)}
        </div>
    )
}
```